# Angular 7 + Ionic 4 build failing "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')"

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like some help with a problem with building my Angular 7 & Ionic 4 app...

If I run `ng build --prod` comand i get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ionic4-auto-complete/fesm5/ionic4-auto-complete.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
    at visitNodes (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16144:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16370:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16265:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16322:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16333:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\MAMP\htdocs\myProject\employeeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16229:21)
```

This is my **package.json** file:

```
"@angular/animations": "^11.0.7",
"@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
"@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
"cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"ionic4-auto-complete": "^2.8.2",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng2-date-picker": "^2.11.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.1",
"sass": "^1.49.9",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.29"
```

I have been googling this issue for some hours now and have no idea what to do.. this is my first Angular + Ionic app so I'm still learning... Am I doing something wrong? Should I use a different build command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dealing a lot with this issue while developing my first Angular application. Nowhere to be found on the Internet how to deal with this issue, I tried and failed to resolve this error. Until I went to production (in which the error didnt seem to come up at all), and then I found out about **buildOptimizer**.

We were developing angular 7 app - I had global version 13.0 of Angular, so there was a version mismatch - on my colleague's pc, where he had ang7 installed, he also didnt get the error at all. So I'm assuming it's because of the version mismatch.

Here included snippet of angular.json, where to find the buildOptimizer. Notice you have to change it from **true** to **false**.

[angular.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wzjt.png)

Comment: This is actually a good answer and your assumption is correct... my global Angular version is 12.2... I have seen this solution but I don't understand what it does and am not sure if its ok to just change this setting

Comment: This was also my concern when disabling the buildOptimizer, but I've tested it thoroughly and It doesnt seem to mess anything up. You can still also downgrade your global Angular to your project Angular version for the time developing in Angular7